# Access different apache servers using a single port number

Tags: apache, http

I have three different web servers in my internal lab and each one of them have its own database and web content. How can I access each one of them from the internet without mapping a different port on my firewall for each one of them?

In other words, can I set up a fourth apache server that checks when aconnection comes http://mydomain.com/WebServer1 to it sends the user to my server one on my internal network and http://mydomain.com/WebServer2, it redirect him to server 2 without having to open a port for the other 3 servers only for the main web server? I have attached a diagram to show my set up.
Thanks in advance

[image: Apache servers lab diagram]

Comment: Yes you can. That's using the red one as a reverse proxy.

Comment: When the initial server (red) receives the request, will it know which of the other three has the content being requested? Or will it forward the request to all three at once, and see which one responds?